# Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(1+2^n)}{\log(1+3^n)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, power-series

How to calculate this limit?
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(1+2^n)}{\log(1+3^n)}$$

Comment: Can you calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log 2^n}{\log 3^n}$ instead? Can you see why both limits are the same?

Comment: What have you tried and which theorems do you know? Consider using l'Hospital if you know it.

Answer (score 3):

Using continuity (fill in details):

$$\frac{\log(1+2^n)}{\log(1+3^n)}=\frac{n\log 2+\log\left(1+\frac1{2^n}\right)}{n\log 3+\log\left(1+\frac1{3^n}\right)}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{\log2}{\log3}$$

Comment: $ n \log 2 + \log ( 1 + \frac{1}{2^n} ) = \log 2^n + \log ( \frac{2^n + 1}{2^n} ) = \log 2^n + \log(2^n + 1) - \log 2^n = \log( 2^n + 1 )$

Comment: remember $\log a^b = b \log a $ and $\log ( \frac{a}{b} ) = \log a - \log b $

Comment: @WillieRosario Hmmm...was that for me, including the downvote?

Comment: To help the asker since your answer might be very hard to follow for a beginner.

Comment: @WillieRosario How can that be "very" hard to follow as this is a calculus question and thus logarithms should be old stuff for him/her? Besides this, it is written "fill in details", for the OP to do some work on his own. And why the downvote?

Comment: I didnt downvote tho

Comment: Oh, ok then....

Comment: Don't worry about downvotes ! You do a good job and this is the most important. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks. Of course I don't worry about them, yet I'd be always interested to know the reason for a downvote.

Comment: This is the big question nobody will never be able to answer !

Comment: @Timbuc I actually got to the near final phase: $\frac{n\log 2+\log\left(1+\frac1{2^n}\right)}{n\log 3+\log\left(1+\frac1{3^n}\right)}$ but didn't how to continue. How do you conclude that's the limit?

Comment: @Jonathan Arithmetic of limits, using that $\;\frac{an}{bn}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac ab\;$

Comment: @Timbuc Thanks! But what about the logs? I mean, can i just assume that when n goes to infinity all i'm left with is $\frac{n log(2)}{n log(3)}$?

Comment: @jonathan: that part is precisely the nice, easy one: that's a rational function, with numerator polynomial of degree $\;1\;$, namely $\;\log2\cdot n\;$ , and likewise with the denominator's polynomial, and since both polynomials are of the same degree the limit in infinity is just main coefficient of numerator divided by main  coefficient of denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\log(1+2^n)=\log(2^{-n}+1)+\log(2^n)$